# Plugin org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin?

Tags: java, spring-boot

When my spring-boot code is executed, I get the error as below:

Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.2.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project projectName: Unable to find a suitable main class, please add a 'mainClass' property

How can I solve this?

Comment: Do you have a class containing a main method in your project? Would you mind post your package structure and point the class containing the main method?

Answer (score 0):

Add a mainclass to the plugin configuration

```
<build>
  ...
  <plugins>
    ...
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <mainClass>your.class.with.main.Method</mainClass>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    ...
  </plugins>
  ...
</build>
```

Source: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/usage.html